# Need a bash scripts to move files to sub folders automatically

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 320G images, I want to move the images to 5 sub folders randomly(just need to move to 5 sub folders). But I know nothing on bash scripts.Please could someone help? thanks!

Comment: You'll want to learn about commands like cp and mkdir.  The internet probably has some info on them. You can also google "bash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any scripting language will do so I'll write in Python here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import random

new_paths = ['/path1', '/path2', '/path3', '/path4', '/path5']
image_directory = '/path/to/images'
for file_path in os.listdir(image_directory):
    full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(image_directory, file_path))

    random_subdir = random.choice(new_paths)
    new_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(random_subdir, file_path))

    os.rename(full_path, new_path)
```

Comment: Yes it will be slow, in general it takes a long time to move 320G. Also, if you truly want them to be random, it will take longer. I wouldn't actually recommend using `random.choice` but instead splitting the subdir up into 5 even pieces and then just moving them based on that.

Answer (score 3):

You could move the files do different directories based on their first letter:

```
mv [A-Fa-f]* dir1
mv [F-Kf-k]* dir2
mv [^A-Ka-k]* dir3
```

Comment: thanks,but I get error mv: cannot stat `[A-FA-f]*': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this. In order to use it place the script somewhere else (not in you folder) but run it from your folder. If you call your script file rmove.sh, you can place it in, say ~/scripts/, then cd to your folder and run:

> source ~/scripts/rmove.sh

```
#/bin/bash

ndirs=$((`find -type d | wc -l` - 1))

for file in *; do
        if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
                rand=`dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null | hexdump -b | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f2`
                rand=$((rand % ndirs))

                i=0
                for directory in `find -type d`; do
                        if [ "${directory}" = . ]; then
                                continue
                        fi
                        if [ $i -eq $rand ]; then
                                mv "${file}" "${directory}"
                        fi
                        i=$((i + 1))
                done
        fi
done
```

Comment: This assumes that you have the folders created. Create them with mkdir otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab at the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sdprefix=subdir
dirs=5

# pre-create all possible sub dirs
for n in {1..5} ; do
    mkdir -p "${sdprefix}$n"
done

fcount=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file ; do
    subdir="${sdprefix}"$(expr \( $RANDOM % $dirs \) + 1)

    mv -f "$file" "$subdir"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

- Works with huge numbers of files
- Does not beak if a file is not moveable
- Creates subdirectories if necessary
- Does not break on unusual file names
- Relatively cheap

Comment: for this script,I get this error:~/root/ok.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/root/ok.sh: line 17: `done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Answer (score -1):

```
mv `ls | while read x; do echo "`expr $RANDOM % 1000`:$x"; done \
| sort -n| sed 's/[0-9]*://' | head -1` ./DIRNAME
```

run it in your current image directory, this command will select one file at a time and move it to `./DIRNAME`, iterate this command until there are no more files to move.

Pay attention that ` is **backquotes** and not just quotes characters.